# Python: How to map numbers to unique items (enumerate unique objects) in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping, enumerate

I need to assign numbers to unique values from a specific column in a dataframe, and make it as a new column...

For example:

```
ex_list=['12-B', '10002', '3A', '4', 'DCX', '3A']
df=pd.DataFrame(ex_list, columns=['Items'])
```

[image: My dataframe]

This is the **expected output**:

[image: Expected dataframe]

*Please note that I need to do this for a dataframe with over 1M rows, so definitely would appreciate an efficient approach!*

Comment: `df['Num_Items'] = df['Items'].factorize()[0]`?

Comment: or `df['Num_Items'] = df.groupby('Items').ngroup()`

Comment: How can  it be based on the `"Now, I can generate numbers based on count of unique items:"` Unique items? Because of you take the count it should be `all the Num_items column value be equal to 1, EXCEPT 3A Item column value which would be 2 right?"`

Comment: @QuangHoang Can you please explain `[0]` that you include at the end?

Comment: `factorize` returns a tuple of two: the codes, which is what you want, and the decodes, which is equivalent to `df['Items'].uniques()`. You can print `df['Items'].factorize()` to see the details.

Comment: @Joe Please read the post carefully... "For example". It is a common practice to provide smaller sets that can be easily recreated by people answering; I don't think including my actual 1M> set is reasonable for many reasons.

Comment: @DGomonov I get it, how can there be a 0 value then if it is a count result? certainly the entry `12-B` accounts to 1 already right?

Comment: @Joe Perhaps you are misunderstanding this... In this case I wanted correct amount of numbers that I would be able to assign/map to each item later; therefore, here 0 is not a value but a pointer to value 12-B. However based on `.factorize()[0]` there was no need to do what I did there as _factorize()_ does that for me (_This method is useful for obtaining a numeric representation of an array when all that matters is identifying distinct values_). Such assignment is very useful for preparing df for later machine learning use (in my case it is Classification).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

```
import pandas as pd
ex_list=['12-B', '10002', '3A', '4', 'DCX', '3A']
df=pd.DataFrame(ex_list, columns=['Items'])
df['Num_Items']=pd.factorize(df['Items'].tolist())[0]
```

Output

```
    Items   Num_Items
0   12-B    0
1   10002   1
2   3A      2
3   4       3
4   DCX     4
5   3A      2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ex_list=['12-B', '10002', '3A', '4', 'DCX', '3A']
df=pd.DataFrame(ex_list, columns=['Items'])
```

Get the unique values from your column, create a mapping between those unique items and integers and then apply that mapping along the `Items` column.

```
mapping = {item:i for i, item in enumerate(df["Items"].unique())}
df["Num_Items"] = df["Items"].apply(lambda x: mapping[x])
df
```

[image: desired output]